# Seeking marriage record of Pierce Butler and Anne Reynolds before 1832 in Ireland?

Tags: birth-records, ireland, 1830s

I am seeking Catherine Marie Butler's PARENTS' names, their birth, death, etc., because I found and have copies of Catherine's name listed in "THE IRELAND, SELECT CATHOLIC BIRTH AND BAPTISM REGISTERS, 1763-1912" as "SEPT 9, 1832 - BAPTISM PLACE: WESTLAND ROW, DUBLIN, IRELAND - CATHERINE M. BUTLER - FATHER: PIERCE BUTLER, MOTHER: ANNE - SS - MICHAEL REDMOND, CATH WHITE" (I don't know what the column "SS" means, and I assume Michael Redmond and Cath White were her godparents/witnesses?)

Our historic and large family records and trees passed down through my generations show Catherine being born on 9/5/1832, baptized 4 days later, and listing her parents as PIERCE BUTLER & ANNE REYNOLDS, but I haven't found details on them!

Our family records show that Catherine was born into wealth and nobility, so I, through research, suspect that PIERCE'S MIDDLE NAME MIGHT BE "SOMERSET", born 1/25/1801, died 7/28/1865, maybe lived in Kilkenny Castle.

He was an Irish politician in the United Kingdom House of Commons. On 2/3/1855, he married Jessy Anne Warren who could be his 2nd wife after Catherine's mother died and after she and Thomas immigrated to America in 1850.

I HAVE much info on Catherine: born 9/5/1832 in Dublin to "Pierce and Anne"; maybe in Kilkenny Castle? She died in Pass Christian, MS on 4/22/1889 and is buried in St. Paul's Catholic Cemetery along with her husband, Charles Aloysius McDonald (10/22/1821 - 2/20/1890). I have copies of their marriage certificate and of their "Find A Graves" which I have visited several times.  Catherine's parents are not listed.

After Catherine's mother died, her father remarried sometime before Catherine was 17 because she at age 17, AGAINST HER FATHER'S WISHES & DEMANDS - HE EVEN THREATENED TO DISINHERIT HER, immigrated to America, (I HAVE COPIES OF THE SHIP'S PASSENGER LIST), arriving in New Orleans on the ship GEORGE EVANS on 11/23/1850 with her younger brother, Thomas Butler, so that she could be governess to the children of her cousins, Percival Butler McCutchon and Jane Butler Browder McCutchon who lived in New Orleans. Percival and Jane were cousins who married each other: his and her mothers were sisters whose Father was Col. William Butler, one of the "FIGHTING BUTLERS".

In New Orleans on 1/11/1853, Catherine married another Irish immigrant, Charles Aloysius McDonald (a 31-year-old widower - his 1st wife was Kate Redmond - with 3 young children, who had immigrated to America in 1849, landing in New York, then moving to New Orleans). Charles was a brick mason.

Charles and Catherine moved to Pass Christian, MS where they raised 9 children, among them being my grandmother, Caroline Elizabeth McDonald, who married William John Bohn. They, too, lived in Pass Christian and raised 6 children, among them my deceased father, Hugh De Lacy Bohn.

Most of these relatives are buried in 2 cemeteries in Pass Christian, MS.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you haven't done so already, please read "What topics can I ask about here?" in the [help/on-topic] and follow the guidance in the section **How to ask questions about ancestors born less than 100 years ago**.  If your father is not yet deceased, please edit your message to remove his name.

Comment: Likewise welcome to G&FH SE!  It sounds to me like the question to ask is "how to locate birth/baptism record for Catherine Butler born 1832 in Ireland?" and to do that there may be evidence as to her parents in her marriage and death/burial records.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to provide us with the information that those records contain, please?

Comment: Please don't be offended that I have removed the sentence mentioning your father's name.  This in line with the comment about our "born within last 100 years policy" mentioned by @JanMurphy, but also by removing it the focus becomes more on finding the vital records of Catherine's parents (your current question) rather than starting to trace out their great grandchildren.

Comment: Did Pierce Butler and Anne Reynolds baptize any other children?  If so, what were the names, dates and locations of those baptisms?  A timeline of these could help with determining whether he may be the Pierce Somerset Butler that you found a baptism for.

Comment: Since you already seem to know the names of Catherine Butler's parents I think you should focus this question on finding vital records for just one of them, and then ask a separate question about the other.  Often by trying to put too much information into a question here it can make it look like too much work for potential answerers to consider tackling.  If you can simplify the question (without losing any information critical to the problem) then I see no reason why it should not attract answers.

Comment: Thank you, Jan Murphy and PolyGeo, for your interest and excellent advice!  I will simplify my question as you suggest and resubmit it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and facts!  It made me realize what I am REALLY seeking:  Ancestry and descendants of Pierce SOMERSET Butler to see if he is my great great grandfather (father of Catherine Marie Butler, my great grandmother)?  If he's not, then I have to look elsewhere for a Pierce Butler.

Comment: This question has always bothered me because I don't see any evidence tying the politician Pierce Somerset Butler to OP's known relative Catherine Marie Butler b. 1832 Dublin to "Pierce and Anne" d. 1889 in Pass Christian, MS. Just "family records show that Catherine was born into wealth and nobility." Is this whole question a case of [premature connectivitis](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9583/10577)?

Answer (score 0):

Pierce Somerset Butler married Jessy Anne Warren, (nee Bryan) a widow, on 3rd February 1835 in London. St. George's.
She was formerly married to Pooley Abel Warren of Kilkenny, in 1828 at Balbriggan.
There was a family scandal involving a lady named Harisson. Details of the court case are contained in Pierce Somerset Butler V. Viscount Mountgarret.